# Sorting on view side with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

How to set up sorting on view side with Rails ?

What is the best way in Rails to setup Sorting on view side ?

Answer (score 1):

By sorting do you mean allowing the user to toggle how data in a table (or the like) is sorted? If so, I'd check out a recent [episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/251-metawhere-metasearch) of railscasts by Ryan Bates on MetaWhere and MetaSearch.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like http://datatables.net/ but it depends on what sort of data you plan to sort, how you need to sort it, and if you can afford to load all of it client-side or not. If you add more detail to your question you can probably get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery Tablesort](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) works great - all client side.